# Joi Validation, prevent a URI from being used

Tags: joi

I have the following field which should accept a YouTube Video ID, I am trying to prevent full URI from being used but cannot seem to find the appropriate use case in Joi Documentation.

```
youtubeVideoId: Joi.string()
    .label('YouTube Video ID')
    .allow(null)
    .allow('')
    .invalid('http', 'www'),
```

I thought the above would work however invalid looks at the string as a whole not contains.

I also tried using but this does not work.

```
youtubeVideoId: Joi.string()
    .label('YouTube Video ID')
    .allow(null)
    .allow('')
    .invalid(Joi.string().uri()),
```

Can anyone provide a Joi validation to prevent a URI from being accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.regex](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/API.md#objectregex) to validate your string.

A youtube video ID is composed by a string with 11 characters, eg: `dQw4w9WgXcQ`

Your regex expression could be this: `/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]{11})$/`

This is how your Joi validation will look like:

```
Joi.object({
    youtubeId: Joi.string().regex(new RegExp(/^([A-Za-z0-9_\-]{11})$/)).required()
})
```

You can find more details about the regex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903823/regex-for-youtube-id) and test it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: You'd get more informative errors out of Joi if you move the character limit to `.max(11)`

Comment: yeah thanks but i ended up using .max(11) as suggested by @Ankh

Comment: Did you use `.max(11)` along with my answer or just `Joi.string().max(11)`?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using .max(11) as suggested by @ankh as this fits the purpose.