# Get YouTube video ID from URL w/ PHP

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, function, youtube

I'm trying to create a function that calls a value from a Wordpress custom field ("_videourl" for a YouTube video URL) and then uses PHP trim to cut it down to just the YouTube video ID. I found a javascript function that cuts down URLs to just the ID but I have no idea how I'd be able to translate that into php (function below):

```
     function youtubeIDextract(url) 
     { 
     var youtube_id; 
     youtube_id = url.replace(/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/,"$1"); 
     return youtube_id; 
     }
```

This PHP function would be used inside the loop so I *think* I would have to use variables, but I'm really just a noob so I have no idea what to do. Can anyone help by sharing their coding expertise in helping me create a PHP function?

**EDIT:SOLVED**

After some experimentation, I found a solution. I wanted to return and post it so that others also in need would have somewhere to start from.

```
function getYoutubeId($ytURL) 
    {
        $urlData = parse_url($ytURL);
        //echo '<br>'.$urlData["host"].'<br>';
        if($urlData["host"] == 'www.youtube.com') // Check for valid youtube url
        {
            $ytvIDlen = 11; // This is the length of YouTube's video IDs

            // The ID string starts after "v=", which is usually right after 
            // "youtube.com/watch?" in the URL
            $idStarts = strpos($ytURL, "?v=");

            // In case the "v=" is NOT right after the "?" (not likely, but I like to keep my 
            // bases covered), it will be after an "&":
            if($idStarts === FALSE)
                $idStarts = strpos($ytURL, "&v=");
            // If still FALSE, URL doesn't have a vid ID
            if($idStarts === FALSE)
                die("YouTube video ID not found. Please double-check your URL.");

            // Offset the start location to match the beginning of the ID string
            $idStarts +=3;

            // Get the ID string and return it
            $ytvID = substr($ytURL, $idStarts, $ytvIDlen);

            return $ytvID;
        }
        else
        {
            //echo 'This is not a valid youtube video url. Please, give a valid url...';
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936467/parse-youtube-video-id-using-preg-match/6382259#6382259 ?

Comment: I higly doubt that YouTube video ids are always 11 chars long. Your regex may be wrong.

Comment: I found some helpful tips in the link Peter, but it doesn't seem any solutions were able to filter out the extra arguments at the end (which is what I need too). I was doing some research and found this: http://www.halgatewood.com/php-get-the-youtube-video-id-from-a-youtube-url/ but I'm not sure how to change it to grab the custom field value for the field '_videoembed'

Comment: @MartinodF- Indeed they are exactly 11 characters long.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get YouTube ID from URL regex pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404752/get-youtube-id-from-url-regex-pattern)

Comment: youtube-nocookie.com is a valid youtube-host.

Answer (score 12):

I had to deal with this for a PHP class i wrote a few weeks ago and ended up with a regex that matches any kind of strings: With or without URL scheme, with or without subdomain, youtube.com URL strings, youtu.be URL strings and dealing with all kind of parameter sorting. You can check it out [at GitHub](https://github.com/eyecatchup/php-yt_downloader/blob/master/youtube-dl.class.php#L259) or simply copy and paste the code block below:

```
/**
 *  Check if input string is a valid YouTube URL
 *  and try to extract the YouTube Video ID from it.
 *  @author  Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 *  @param   $url   string   The string that shall be checked.
 *  @return  mixed           Returns YouTube Video ID, or (boolean) false.
 */        
function parse_yturl($url) 
{
    $pattern = '#^(?:https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch\?v=|/watch\?.+&v=))([\w-]{11})(?:.+)?$#x';
    preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    return (isset($matches[1])) ? $matches[1] : false;
}
```

To explain the regex, here's a spilt up version:

```
/**
 *  Check if input string is a valid YouTube URL
 *  and try to extract the YouTube Video ID from it.
 *  @author  Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 *  @param   $url   string   The string that shall be checked.
 *  @return  mixed           Returns YouTube Video ID, or (boolean) false.
 */        
function parse_yturl($url) 
{
    $pattern = '#^(?:https?://)?';    # Optional URL scheme. Either http or https.
    $pattern .= '(?:www\.)?';         #  Optional www subdomain.
    $pattern .= '(?:';                #  Group host alternatives:
    $pattern .=   'youtu\.be/';       #    Either youtu.be,
    $pattern .=   '|youtube\.com';    #    or youtube.com
    $pattern .=   '(?:';              #    Group path alternatives:
    $pattern .=     '/embed/';        #      Either /embed/,
    $pattern .=     '|/v/';           #      or /v/,
    $pattern .=     '|/watch\?v=';    #      or /watch?v=,    
    $pattern .=     '|/watch\?.+&v='; #      or /watch?other_param&v=
    $pattern .=   ')';                #    End path alternatives.
    $pattern .= ')';                  #  End host alternatives.
    $pattern .= '([\w-]{11})';        # 11 characters (Length of Youtube video ids).
    $pattern .= '(?:.+)?$#x';         # Optional other ending URL parameters.
    preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    return (isset($matches[1])) ? $matches[1] : false;
}
```

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me. Excellent solution and explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the regex is correct, you could use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
$youtubeId = preg_replace('/^[^v]+v.(.{11}).*/', '$1', $url);
```

You may also be interested in [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or [`substr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) as alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I have found;

```
 function GetYouTubeId($url)
 {
 preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);
 $youtube_id = $match[1];
 return $youtube_id;
 }
```