# Get youtube id for all url types

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The following code works with all YouTube domains except for `youtu.be`. An example would be: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZedLgAF9aEg` would turn into: `ZedLgAF9aEg`

My question is how would I be able to make it work with `http://youtu.be/ZedLgAF9aEg`.
I'm not so great with regex so your help is much appreciated. My code is:

```
    $text = preg_replace("#[&\?].+$#", "", preg_replace("#http://(?:www\.)?youtu\.?be(?:\.com)?/(embed/|watch\?v=|\?v=|v/|e/|.+/|watch.*v=|)#i", "", $text)); }
$text = (htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Just so I understand.  You're doing a replace to get the ID?  And you want to get the ID from the short URLs (youtu.be)?  I'll see if I can come up with something real quick before bed, but I would not recommend doing a replace to parse out a simple ID...

Comment: Yeah, im looking to find the id but have it working with both youtube.com aswell as youtu.be, a user will submit a message with their contents and if they wish to include a video they would do; [youtube]video_url[/youtube]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get YouTube ID from URL regex pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404752/get-youtube-id-from-url-regex-pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex appears to solve the problem as it stands now? I didn't try it in php, but it appears to work fine in my editor.

The first part of the regex `http://(?:www\.)?youtu\.?be(?:\.com)?/`matches `http://youtu.be/` and the second part `(embed/|watch\?v=|\?v=|v/|e/|.+/|watch.*v=|)` ends with `|)` which means it matches *nothing* (making it optional). In other words it would trim away `http://youtu.be/` leaving only the id.

A more intuitive way of writing it would be to make the whole if grouping optional I suppose, but as far as I can tell your regex is already solving your problem:

```
 #http://(?:www\.)?youtu\.?be(?:\.com)?/(embed/|watch\?v=|\?v=|v/|e/|.+/|watch.*v=)?#i
```

Note: Your regex would work with the `www.youtu.be.com` domain as well. It would be stripped away, but something to watch out for if you use this for validating input.

**Update:**

If you want to only match urls inside `[youtube][/youtube]` tags you could use [look arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
Something along the lines of:

```
(?<=\[youtube\])(?:http://(?:www\.)?youtu\.?be(?:\.com)?/(?:embed/|watch\?v=|\?v=|v/|e/|[^\[]+/|watch.*v=)?)(?=.+\[/youtube\])
```

You could further refine it by making the `.+` in the look ahead only match valid URL characters etc.

Comment: Your right it does work but in order to make it embeded it needs to be places inbetween [youtube] [/youtube] and the youtu.be url ends up trimming the code box to "[youtube]youtube]" but yet with the other urls it works perfectly. Never noticed that until now.

Comment: The `.+/` portion of the last portion seems to be the culprit. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do you could change it to `[^\[]+/` but I'm sure there are nicer ways of doing it.

e.g. `(embed/|watch\?v=|\?v=|v/|e/|[^\[]+/|watch.*v=)?`

Comment: Well, that worked perfectly! I appreciate it, how would you improve it? And i've got another question that is semi-related, would it be possible to preg_replace only if the user places in between the [youtube]url[/youtube] code braces?

Comment: Updated the answer to include matching the tags. Regarding optimization I'll see what I find the time for later.

Answer (score 3):

```
//$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZedLgAF9aEg';
$url = 'http://youtu.be/ZedLgAF9aEg';

if (FALSE === strpos($url, 'youtu.be/')) {
    parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $id);
    $id = $id['v'];
} else {
    $id = basename($url);
}

echo $id; // ZedLgAF9aEg
```

Will work for both versions of URLs. **Do not** use regex for this as PHP has built in functions for parsing URLs as I have demonstrated which are faster and more robust against breaking.

Comment: While useful, it doesn't work if the url is http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TklgWV06BUc&feature=youtu.be

Comment: `$url = explode('&', $url)[0];` Unless I'm missing a case, this should be sufficient to handle the case where there are additional url parameters

Comment: or just use `if (FALSE === strpos($url, 'youtu.be/')) {` instead. It will check for a trailing slash which the args should not have.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it'll help you

```
function YouTubeUrl($url)
{
if($url!='')
{
    $newUrl='';
    $videoLink1=$url;
    $findKeyWord='youtu.be';
    $toBeReplaced='www.youtube.com';
    if(IsContain('watch?v=',$videoLink1))
    {
        $newUrl=tMakeUrl($videoLink1);
    }
    else if(IsContain($videoLink1, $findKeyWord))
    {
        $videoLinkArray=explode('/',$videoLink1);
        $Protocol='';
        if(IsContain('://',$videoLink1))
        {
            $protocolArray=explode('://',$videoLink1);
            $Protocol=$protocolArray[0];
        }

        $file=$videoLinkArray[count($videoLinkArray)-1];
        $newUrl='www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$file;
        if($Protocol!='')
            $newUrl.=$Protocol.$newUrl;
        else
            $newUrl=tMakeUrl($newUrl);
    }
    else
        $newUrl=tMakeUrl($videoLink1);
    return $newUrl;
}
return '';
}

function IsContain($string,$findKeyWord)
{
     if(strpos($string,$findKeyWord)!==false)
    return true;
     else
    return false;
}

function tMakeUrl($url)
{
$tSeven=substr($url,0,7);
$tEight=substr($url,0,8);
if($tSeven!="http://" && $tEight!="https://")
{
    $url="http://".$url;
}
return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow function for any of youtube  URL

I hope this will help you

function checkYoutubeId($id)

{

$youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=". $id ."&format=json";

$curl = curl_init($youtube);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$return = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

return json_decode($return, true);

}

This function return Youtube video detail if Id match to youtube video ID

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement to @rvalvik answer would be to include the case of the mobile links (I've noticed it while working with a customer who used an iPad to navigate, copy and paste links). In this case, we have a `m` (mobile) letter instead of `www`. Regex then becomes:

```
#(https?://)?(?:www\.)?(?:m\.)?(?:youtu\.be/|youtube\.com(?:/embed/|/v/|/watch?.*?v=))([\w\-]{10,12}).*#x
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This will allow `www.m.` you want to use `(?:(?:www|m)\.)?` or `(?:www\.|m\.)` instead. Either way regex should not be used for this as it is prone to breaking easily if format is changed. PHP has built-in functions which can do the same easily.

Comment: You're right @crypticツ I haven't think about the case of having both `www` and `m`. You've hint at some PHP built-in function to extract YouTube id, can you please give some further detail? Thanks!

Comment: See my posted answer above http://stackoverflow.com/a/15218823/1592648 it will work for any domain, and if arguments are in any order and is much faster than using a regex.

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement of another answer:

```
if (strpos($url, 'feature=youtu.be') === TRUE || strpos($url, 'youtu.be') === FALSE ) 
{
    parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $id);
    $id = $id['v'];
} 
else 
{
    $id = basename($url);
}
```

This takes into account youtu.be still being in the URL, but not the URL itself (it does happen!) as it could be the referring feature link.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers miss out on the point that some youtube links are part of a playlist and have a list paramater also which is required for embed code. So to extract the embed code from link one could try this JS code:

```
    let urlEmbed = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGGolqb6gDE&list=PL2q4fbVm1Ik6DCzm9XZJbNwyHtHGclcEh&index=32"

    let embedId = urlEmbed.split('v=')[1];
    let parameterStringList = embedId.split('&');

    if (parameterStringList.length > 1) {
      embedId = parameterStringList[0];

      let listString = parameterStringList.filter((parameterString) =>
        parameterString.includes('list')
      );

      if (listString.length > 0) {
        listString = listString[0].split('=')[1];
        embedId = `${parameterStringList[0]}?${listString}`;
      }
    }

    console.log(embedId)
```

Try it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/AMITKESARI2000/o62dwj7q/

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
$string = explode("=","http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZedLgAF9aEg");
echo $string[1];
```

**would turn into: `ZedLgAF9aEg`**

Comment: No, what if there is more than one = in there?