# How to get youtube embed code with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, video, youtube, embedding

I need to give the possibility to embed youtube videos in a website I'm developing. The admin shoud be able to insert a youtube link in a form; the url will be stored in the database and then I have to embed it in a page.

I was trying to use this library: http://codeigniter.com/wiki/YouTube_API_for_CodeIgniter/revision/12072/

But using the getVideoEntry function I get this, and I don't really know what to do with it:

```
tag:youtube.com,2008:video:zol2MJf6XNE2009-01-14T17:21:57.000Z2011-09-01T11:36:39.000ZSyndication of this video was restricted by its owner.DominoRecordshttp://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/dominorecordsMusicDominoRecordsA video for 'My Girls' from Animal Collective's new album Merriweather Post Pavilion. Out now on Domino. Produced by: Knowmore Productions Animated by: Jon Vermilyea Edited/VFX by: Chad Von Nauanimal collective, my girls, domino, avey tare, panda bear, geologistDEAnimal Collective - My Girls (2009)widescreen2009-01-14T17:21:57.000Zzol2MJf6XNE
```

And anyway, to use it, I need the youtube video id. Is there an easy way to get it, which covers all possible variations of youtube urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodeIgniter seems like overkill for merely embedding videos.  The YouTube functionality on the page you linked is mostly a wrapper for the YouTube Data API (which allows for extracting information about YT users, channels, videos, etc. and facilitates procedural uploading of videos).  [Embedding videos is as easy as dropping some HTML on your page with the correct video ID.](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?answer=171780)

[Here's the best answer I've seen for getting the video ID from URLs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936467/parse-youtube-video-id-using-preg-match/6382259#6382259)

Comment: well, you're right. For what I need to do I think I can just parse the id and then put it in the embed code. Thanks.