# php- parsing youtube video id

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [parse youtube video id using preg_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936467/parse-youtube-video-id-using-preg-match)

I'd like to extract the youtube video id from an input string via regular expressions. The input is always as follows: `[youtube=-J_JLXuioEI]` and I need the id, which is `-J_JLXuioEI` in this case.
Now I use the following regular expression:

```
preg_match_all('/youtube=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)/', $string, $m );
```

I fear that Google uses other characters like `!` in their ids and so I would like to ask if you have a general id how to parse these ids.

Thanks much in advance,

enne

Comment: It's not the same. AFAIK he's asking to extract the ID from a string, not from Youtube URL.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I can input several such Strings, e.g "[youtube=-J_JLXuioEI] [youtube=-ABCD-EFG] [youtube=-J_JLXuioEV].."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get everything after = and before ]. Like

```
/\[youtube=(.+)\]/
```

Comment: Thanks m0skit0 but I forgot to mention that I can input several such strings like "[youtube=-J_JLXuioEI] [youtube=-ABCD-EFG] [youtube=-J_JLXuioEV].." and this one just works for one.

Comment: Split them then parse one by one.