# getting youtube video id the PHP

Tags: php, url, youtube, get, parse-url

I am currently writing a webapp in which some pages are heavily reliant on being able to pull the correct youtube video in - and play it.  The youtube URLS are supplied by the users and for this reason will generally come in with variants one of them may look like this:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y40ND8kXDlg

while the other may look like this:

> http://www.youtube.com/watch/v/y40ND8kXDlg

Currently I am able to pull the ID from the latter using the code below:

```
function get_youtube_video_id($video_id)
{

    // Did we get a URL?
    if ( FALSE !== filter_var( $video_id, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) )
    {

        // http://www.youtube.com/v/abcxyz123
        if ( FALSE !== strpos( $video_id, '/v/' ) )
        {
            list( , $video_id ) = explode( '/v/', $video_id );
        }

        // http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcxyz123
        else
        {
            $video_query = parse_url( $video_id, PHP_URL_QUERY );
            parse_str( $video_query, $video_params );
            $video_id = $video_params['v'];
        }

    }

    return $video_id;

}
```

How can I deal with URLS that use the `?v` version rather than the `/v/` version?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936467/parse-youtube-video-id-using-preg-match

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831191/....

Comment: Er, the above code already works with the first URL?

Comment: #2 comment is easiest way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392993/php-regex-to-get-youtube-video-id

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like this:

```
$link = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0";
$video_id = explode("?v=", $link);
$video_id = $video_id[1];
```

Here is universal solution:

```
$link = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0&lololo";
$video_id = explode("?v=", $link); // For videos like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...
if (empty($video_id[1]))
    $video_id = explode("/v/", $link); // For videos like http://www.youtube.com/watch/v/..

$video_id = explode("&", $video_id[1]); // Deleting any other params
$video_id = $video_id[0];
```

Or just use this regex:

```
(\?v=|/v/)([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)
```

Comment: This will not always work. If you copy/paste urls from youtube website, there are often other parameters, such as `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0&player=normal&... There can be a dozen of these.  Your code will produce the ID of `oHg5SJYRHA0&player=normal&...` - which is clearly wrong

Comment: Fixed that. Look at the new solution.

Comment: Or look at my code here: https://github.com/lingtalfi/video-ids-and-thumbnails/blob/master/testvideo.php It handles various youtube urls, and vimeo and dailymotion too.

Answer (score 12):

```
<?php
// Here is a sample of the URLs this regex matches: (there can be more content after the given URL that will be ignored)

// http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/e/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/user/username#p/u/11/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/sandalsResorts#p/c/54B8C800269D7C1B/0/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

// It also works on the youtube-nocookie.com URL with the same above options.
// It will also pull the ID from the URL in an embed code (both iframe and object tags)

preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);
$youtube_id = $match[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$your_url='https://www.youtube.com/embed/G_5-SqD2gtA';
function get_youtube_id_from_url($url)
{
    if (stristr($url,'youtu.be/'))
        {preg_match('/(https:|http:|)(\/\/www\.|\/\/|)(.*?)\/(.{11})/i', $url, $final_ID); return $final_ID[4]; }
    else 
        {@preg_match('/(https:|http:|):(\/\/www\.|\/\/|)(.*?)\/(embed\/|watch.*?v=|)([a-z_A-Z0-9\-]{11})/i', $url, $IDD); return $IDD[5]; }
}

echo get_youtube_id_from_url($your_url)
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
function youtubeID($url){
     $res = explode("v",$url);
     if(isset($res[1])) {
        $res1 = explode('&',$res[1]);
        if(isset($res1[1])){
            $res[1] = $res1[0];
        }
        $res1 = explode('#',$res[1]);
        if(isset($res1[1])){
            $res[1] = $res1[0];
        }
     }
     return substr($res[1],1,12);
     return false;
 }
$url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch/v/y40ND8kXDlg";
echo youtubeID($url1);
```

Should work for both

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is a much better answer than my previous:

```
  $link = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0&player=normal';

  strtok($link, '?');

  parse_str(strtok(''));

  echo $v;
```

It's might be good to have this in a function to keep the new variables out of the global scope (unless you want them there, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

This may not be in use still, but there might be other people looking for an answer, so, to get a YouTube ID from a URL.

P.S: This works for all types of URL, I've tested it;

```
Function getYouTubeID($URL){
    $YouTubeCheck = preg_match('![?&]{1}v=([^&]+)!', $URL . '&', $Data);
    If($YouTubeCheck){
        $VideoID = $Data[1];
    }
    Return $VideoID;
}
```

Or just use the preg_match function itself;

```
If(preg_match('![?&]{1}v=([^&]+)!', $URL . '&', $Data)){
        $VideoID = $Data[1];
}
```

Hope this helps someone :)!

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method I know with YouTube.

```
 function GetYouTubeId($url)
 {
 preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);
 $youtube_id = $match[1];
 return $youtube_id;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = explode('=', $link);

// $parts[1] will y40ND8kXDlg
```

This example works only if there's one '=' in the URL. Ever likely to be more?

Comment: If you copy/paste urls from youtube website, there are often other parameters, such as `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0&player=normal&... There can be a dozen of these.

Answer (score 0):

i just would search for the last "/" or the last "=". After it you find always the video-id.

Comment: This might work with the `/` URL, but will not always work with the other type.  If you copy/paste urls from youtube website, there are often other parameters, such as http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0&player=normal&... There can be a dozen of these.  Judge for yourself what will happen if you search for the last `=`

Comment: oh thats right. but if you search for the first appearance of "v=" or "v/" you get the start of the id. the end of the id is the end of the string or the next "&".

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("#([\w\d\-]){11}#is", 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y40ND8kXDlg', $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is best way to get youtube vedio id  , Or any field in url , but you must change index (V) from $ID_youtube['v'] to anything you want.

```
function getID_youtube($url)
{
    parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $ID_youtube);
    return $ID_youtube['v'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$link = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0";
$video_id = str_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=', '', $link);
echo $video_id;
?>
```

Output:
    **oHg5SJYRHA0**

**[Source](http://www.randelx.com)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKW_FPsFiB8&feature=related";
parse_str( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_QUERY ), $vid );
echo $vid['v'];    

?>
```

Output: uKW_FPsFiB8

This will work for urls like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKW_FPsFiB8&feature=related or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzH8FH1HF3A&feature=relmfu or only https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uKW_FPsFiB8

Answer (score 0):

All YouTube video ids are 11 characters of length. I wrote Regex based it:

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gooWdc6kb80";

preg_match('/(?:\/|=)(.{11})(?:$|&|\?)/', $url, $matches);

echo $matches[1];

?>
```

It can match different YouTube video formats:

```
// http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/e/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/user/username#p/u/11/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/sandalsResorts#p/c/54B8C800269D7C1B/0/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
// https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?feature=oembed
// https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?start=16&feature=oembed
```