# preg_match does not get code from all youtube links. how to fix?

Tags: php, youtube

I am using the following code to get youtube code in a long script. It works with this link

"bla bla bla bla http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kkLTxsAhURw bla bla"
but it does not work in this link
""bla bla bla bla http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3YDz-ftqr1g bla bla"

It gets '3YDz' before the - but not the rest.. How can i get all code from the second link? Thanks.

```
preg_match('~v=([A-Za-z0-9]+)~', $txt, $match);
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the missing minus in the regex?

Comment: `~v=([\-A-Za-z0-9]+)~`

Answer (score 0):

A little edit:

```
preg_match('@v=([\-A-Za-z0-9]+)@', $txt, $match);
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the "-" when its the first one.

Answer (score 0):

As others said but you can shorten the regx a bit.

```
preg_match('\v=([-\w]+)\', $txt, $match);
```

Demo

http://regex101.com/r/tM2hU3/1

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will tend to work, however this is a somewhat more robust regex:

```
<?php
$string = "This is video on youtube **http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKTBUmrwYDs**";

preg_match( '#http(s?)://(((www\.)?youtube\.com)|(youtu\.be))/((watch.*(\?|\&)v=([^&]+))|((embed/)?([a-z0-9\-_]+))|)#i' , $string , $matches );

$youtube_id = array_pop( $matches );
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked on SO many times before...

Here is one with an answer that should work for you as well:
[parse youtube video id using preg_match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936467/parse-youtube-video-id-using-preg-match?rq=1)

The regex:

```
if (preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match)) {
    $video_id = $match[1];
}
```